# Linux (unix) bash, import multiple fgdb to PostGIS using find & ogr2ogr command

Tags: postgis, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, bash

I have multiple file geodatabases in different folders and this is the command I made so far:

````
find -path "*/V*/*.gdb" -o -path "*/W*/*.gdb" -o -path "*/R*/*.gdb" -o -path "*/WM*/*.gdb" | while read filename;
do ogr2ogr -update -append -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES --config FGDB_BULK_ROAD YES -f "PostgreSQL" \
PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres" ${filename} done;```
````

Here, when I just typed:

```
find -path "*/V*/*.gdb" -o -path "*/W*/*.gdb" -o -path "*/R*/*.gdb" -o -path "*/WM*/*.gdb" | while read filename; do echo $filename; done;
```

then I get `./Vblahbah/file.gdb`

Since *.gdb is being recognized as folder in Linux, I think using `find -path` is the best option that I can think of

but when I executed the command I get this error

> Unable to open datasource './RRLM171G0WRR000FZZBB/file.gdb' with the following drivers.

but it does look like the file geodatabase is being imported to PostGIS.

[image: v]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have checked your approach against a gdb I have and I can get it to work if I drop the `-config FGDB_BULK_ROAD` switch. ogr2ogr is quite fussy, and doesn't always give very clear errors. There is nothing wrong with your bash script, though.

Comment: even after i drop the fgdb bulk road switch. it still gives me the same error :(

Comment: i dropped the config and added -lco Spatial_index=no  then it now gives me no errors ..

Comment: It is a violation of best practice to load *any* data using the 'postgres' user or into the 'postgres' database, and publishing passwords on the Internet is not necessary (or wise).  File geodatabases are *container objects* -- they do not contain data, just tables (in which the data is stored) and metadata. A file geodatabase will *always* be represented as a directory by the operating system (unless it has been hopelessly corrupted).